# Angular material table - accessible issue - not able to access using keyboard

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, mat-table

I am developing an application and it should be accessible by keyboard and screen reader. I am using angular material table to display data in table format. The only problem here is that it's not accessible by keyboard.

Here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jbmjajnqnqe?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Is this a known bug?

Comment: What do you mean accessible by keyboard? What should it do?

Comment: it IS accessible. arrows navigation is working and reading every cell with its row/col index and content if any screen reader soft is opened. If it is not opened most of keyboard navigation shouldn't work

Comment: @MCMatan - I am not able to navigate through all cells and rows using keyboard (tabs & arrow keys)

Comment: @Andrei - For me, It's not working with screen reader also.